# View.findNavController() vs Fragment.findNavController()

Tags: android-architecture-components, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

Anywhere in a `NavHostFragment` I can do `findNavController().navigateUp()`

Or, if in my Fragment I have a button to be used for navigation, I could do either:

```
editButton.setOnClickListener { v ->
    v.findNavController().navigateUp()
}
```

or

```
editButton.setOnClickListener {
    findNavController().navigateUp()
}
```

Why would I use one extension function vs the other when setting up a button click listener in a Fragment?

Answer (score 19):

They are almost the same, `Fragment.findNavController()` is just a handy shortcut, it actually calls `Navigation.findNavController(view)` at the end. Both of them are getting the `NavController` from the root view of the fragment.

```
// NavHostFragment.java
public static NavController findNavController(@NonNull Fragment fragment) {
    ....
    View view = fragment.getView();
    if (view != null) {
        return Navigation.findNavController(view);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that. What about the code part above it that handles NavHostFragment differently?

Comment: afaik, there is no difference, they search for a `NavController` from the root view of the fragment.

Comment: I am thinking that one reason the view one would be preferred is a slight performance improvement as a result of using the view right away rather than doing the `NavHostFragment` checks first and then falling back on the view.

Answer (score 4):

Thank you for the Java answer, I offer a ViewBinding solution in kotlin, doing the same

```
// NavHostFragment.kotlin
fun findMyNavController(@NonNull fragment: Fragment): NavController {
    return Navigation.findNavController(binding.root)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Although they are not identical as suggested by the top voted answer, the performance difference should be negligible in general scenarios. ***However if you use the  `v.findNavController()` on a `View` which is deeply nested down, then you should prefer `Fragment` extension `findNavController()` as it will perform better***.

In general I don't see any reason to prefer the `v.findNavController` over the `Fragment` extension. following is the complete code of this method from `NavHostFragment` and it only calls `Navigation.findNavController` if it doesn't find the `NavController` using the fragment

```
public static NavController findNavController(@NonNull Fragment fragment) {
    Fragment findFragment = fragment;
    while (findFragment != null) {
        if (findFragment instanceof NavHostFragment) {
            return ((NavHostFragment) findFragment).getNavController();
        }
        Fragment primaryNavFragment = findFragment.requireFragmentManager()
                 .getPrimaryNavigationFragment();
        if (primaryNavFragment instanceof NavHostFragment) {
            return ((NavHostFragment) primaryNavFragment).getNavController();
        }
        findFragment = findFragment.getParentFragment();
    }

    // Try looking for one associated with the view instead, if applicable
    View view = fragment.getView();
    if (view != null) {
        return Navigation.findNavController(view);
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException("Fragment " + fragment
                + " does not have a NavController set");
}
```